# When is PureRenderMixin not appropriate?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

My project uses Redux, Immutable.js, and React.  I know from [the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html) that the `PureRenderMixin` works well with Redux/Flux. The last sentence especially:

> [If our stores are immutable.js structures, and] we also use
>   immutable-js data structures to hold the components' state, we could
>   mix PureRenderMixin into all our components and short circuit the
>   re-rendering process.

I'm not 100% certain, but I think from context that 'short-circuiting the re-rendering process' is a good thing, so it sounds like one ought to use `PureRenderMixin` all the time with fully immutable data structures.

But then, [this article](http://jamesknelson.com/should-i-use-shouldcomponentupdate/) discusses the performance boosts, and advises:

> "Use shouldComponentUpdate once you’ve measured that it provides a
>   perceivable performance improvement."

This doesn't seem like a generalizable answer so much as a tautology ("use it if it's better than not using it").

Most other literature on `PureRenderMixin` suggests just using it on "pure" components (i.e., those that will render the same output consistently when provided the same props/state).

Is it accurate to conclude, then, that nearly *all* components meet this criteria, so long as they don't make API calls (i.e., load external data) or mutate their state/props?

If that's the case, besides the rare "non-pure" component, when shouldn't one use PureRenderMixin?